# Controlling two devices with one switch

Tags: control, switching

I have a bathroom light over the sink and an exhaust fan wired to the same switch.  I added an LED flood over the shower and wired it to the fan as that was the most accessible place to get power.  What I would like is to have the flood only be on every third or fourth or time the switch is operated.  I thought I'd be able to find some kind of stepper relay that would do the job but haven't yet.  If this could be done with just the existing 120v AC on the circuit, that would be ideal.

Comment: Doesn't sound trivial. You'd need to make/find/buy the equipment and install it. So why not install a second switch for the flood? Sounds like it would be cheaper and an easier install...

Comment: I'm kind of intrigued by a light that only comes on sometimes. What is the purpose of this? Is it just to confuse guests?

Comment: My wife would like to soak in the tub without the floodlight in her eyes.  I would like to avoid installing a new box and fishing wire to it. Attic access above the existing switch is not good. @PkP  I may just use an X10 module.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a relay driven by a small micro all fed from the mains power.
The mico is powered from a simple mains dropper and counts the number of times the power is applied - needs to store this in its non volatile memory. It can then power the relay feeding power to the flood once every four operations.